# lappending a range of list to another list

Tags: tcl

```
set mac_list ""
set new_mac_list "1111.1111.1111 2222.2222.2222 3333.3333.3333 4444.4444.4444"
lappend mac_list [lrange new_mac_list $i end]
```

i value is always 3 at this point in my script
the concept is i always want mac_address of new_mac_list list from lindex 3 in my mac_list

it works fine when i have 4 mac address as above in new_mac_list
but when new_mac_list has less than 4 mac address i get {} value to my mac_list
and when new_mac_list has more than 4 mac address i get whole remaining list elements as a single element in mac_list..

Comment: Note that list indexing is zero-based, so your example, the value at index 3 is "4444.4444.4444". If your list has less than 4 elements, the range from index 3 to the end is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how you append multiple elements (tcl8.5+):

```
lappend mac_list {*}[lrange $new_mac_list $i end]
```

Older TCL would require

```
set mac_list [concat $mac_list [lrange $new_mac_list $i end]]
```

Comment: tnx it works, but  didnt understand how the first one (tcl8.5) works?? what does {*} actually mean??

Comment: {*} splices lists into the command. For details, see TIP 293: http://www.tcl.tk/cgi-bin/tct/tip/293